# A wish that fulfills 3 wishes together

Tags: logical-deduction, situation

This is a riddle , which has been solved before but is fun and interesting so sharing with all here :-

I lived in a family with my wife and my parents . Suddenly I found a magic lamp , where from rubbing it came a genie, and he said that I can ask only 1 wish .

I had no real wish I would want to get fulfilled. So before I asked any wish I went and asked my wife and my parents if they want some sort of wish to get fulfilled. Here are their wishes :-

$(i)$ My mother was blind . She wished to cure her blindness.

$(ii)$ My family never had any children . So my wife wished for a son .

$(iii)$ My father always wanted to be rich . So he wished for a bag of gold coins.

Now I am in a trouble . What wish should I ask to the genie so that I can make everyone happy with their needs, and everyone gets what they want?

**Note** :- You cannot use a wish to make it wish for more wishes . Or else this wouldn't have been a puzzle :) .

I am looking for a creative answer , that only fulfills only the 3 wishes given by my wife and my parents .

Comment: I edited my answer based on your recent edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wish could be:

> I wish for my mother to see my wife'son with a bag full of gold coins in his hands.

Comment: Exactly the answer which I was looking for !!

Comment: The father gets a rich grandson, but he still doesn't have the bag of gold he asked for. Do we assume he just takes it from the kid?

Comment: @NuclearWang of course not, he exchanges it for a lollipop ;)

Answer (score 4):

Wish for

> Every member of your immediate family to have their greatest desire come true.

Comment: There's a better answer than that . But it isn't wrong .

Answer (score 2):

As a refinement to Pierre Schneegans's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101120/9422) that includes your father's wish, you could wish:

> that your mother could see your (wife's) son give a bag of gold to your father.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody knows that the first thing you should do when you find a genie lamp is to

> wish for more wishes

which will allow you to wish for anything you want.

EDIT: Since you are only allowed to ask this genie for 1 wish, you should instead

> wish for another magic lamp.

Comment: !!! 14 seconds!!

Comment: It says in the question you can only have 1 wish

Comment: Beat your edit by 25 seconds :):)

Answer (score 1):

You should wish for

> infinite wishes!

or something of that sort...

Or even

> for all your family's dreams to come true!

Or maybe (if you're feeling fun) ask for

> two more genies!

Comment: It says in the question you can only have 1 wish

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil -- But it doesn't say your one wish can't be to have multiple other wishes!

Comment: I think thats implied. You only have 1 so you cannot wish a second time. Sure you can wish for more wishes, but you wont be able to use them

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil -- Now that the question's been edited, I see; you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could wish for

> your wife to give birth to a successful optometrist (an eye doctor). That would cure your mother's blindness, give your wife a son, and make money for your father.

Comment: Aah good answer with some twist . However in that case my son has to work hard enough to earn money for my father , if my son would be a mediocre , then it's tough to bring a bag of gold coins .